# TabControl create one like a browser

Tags: c#, winforms, label, tabcontrol

I am working on a web browser project I want to make a web browser I used ToolStrip to put all the functions of the web browser(favorite, history, home, GO, back, forward). What I want now is to make tha Tabs.

1) what do you think the best way to implement the tabs is it TabControl or is there another way.

2) how do I make to click on a label next to each tab  and I open the new tab with a label next to it. So I can open a third one and so on.

I found this code, but it does not add dynamically and it add the second tab with leaving the label on the first tab

```
this.tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage2;
```

Comment: Which UI framework? WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, XNA? (Okay, probably not XNA.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) i made a tabcontrol and deleted all the tabs in the form
2)i made a button look like a plus and one looks like a minus and added this code:

```
        int Counter = 1;
        this.tabControl1.TabPages.Add("Page " + Counter);
        this.tabControl1.SelectTab(Counter - 1);
        Counter = Counter + 1;
```

this will add a new tab with title page (1,2,3,4,..,n) and then i put a code when i press go to the specified Url:

```
RequestAndResponsHelper RS = new RequestAndResponsHelper(Url.Text);
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        s = RS.GetRequest();//get the request from a different class
        string HtmlString = s.ToString();

        rtb = new RichTextBox();
        rtb.AppendText(HtmlString);
        rtb.Name = "RichText";
        rtb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(rtb);
```